# Python calling method without 'self'

Tags: python, class, self

So I just started programming in python and I don't understand the whole reasoning behind 'self'. I understand that it is used almost like a global variable, so that data can be passed between different methods in the class. I don't understand why you need to use it when your calling another method in the same class. If I am already in that class, why do I have to tell it??

example, if I have:
Why do I need self.thing()?

```
class bla:
    def hello(self):
        self.thing()

    def thing(self):
        print "hello"
```

Comment: Open a Python interpreter and run `import this` for an explanation of most of Python's language decisions.

Comment: @ColinValliant: Obscure and versatile doctrinal statements like "*Now is better than never. Although never is often better than *right* now.*" can only be interpreted by an enlightened Pythoness and don't really help answering the question.

Answer (score 76):

Also you can make methods in class `static` so no need for `self`. However, use this if you really need that.

Yours:

```
class bla:
    def hello(self):
        self.thing()

    def thing(self):
        print "hello"
```

static edition:

```
class bla:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        bla.thing()

    @staticmethod
    def thing():
        print "hello"
```

Comment: I know this is an older post, but would you mind to give an example of a scenario in which one would use a static method?

Comment: @uitty400 Static methods operate on one or more static variables. For instance, you have a static variable keeping count of the number of instances created so far. A static method could then be used to, say, increment that counter.

Comment: @uitty400 non-static methods can access static variables, but static methods can't access non-static variables.

Comment: @Developer, you don't need the self argument in `thing` definition.  This is support for not using `@staticmethod` at all and just referring to the methods by the class name prefix

Comment: Even if I do not use `self` , it works without using the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: @Volatil3 that is correct. But it is a good practice to marc the method as static to show other developers it was *intended* to be static and consequently not having the 'self'

Answer (score 15):

One reason is to refer to the method of that *particular* class's instance within which the code is be executed.

This example might help:

```
def hello():
    print "global hello"

class bla:
    def hello(self):
        self.thing()
        hello()

    def thing(self):
        print "hello"

b = bla()
b.hello()
>>> hello
global hello
```

You can think of it, for now, to be namespace resolution.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried below code that declared method with out parameter in class and called method using class name.

```
class Employee:

    def EmpWithOutPar():
        return 'Hi you called Employee'

print(Employee.EmpWithOutPar())
```

output :
Hi you called Employee

Comment: what does the decorator `@staticmethod` from @Developers answers is then needed for?

Comment: Just to clarify, the difference is that you call the class directly and do not instatiate it (`emp = Employee()`), thus you do not need the decorator (`@staticmethod`). However if one wants a class that you can instatiate as well as has the ability to call static methods you can use the decorator.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "because you can `def thing(args)` as a global function, or as a method of another class. Take this (horrible) example:

```
def thing(args):
    print "Please don't do this."

class foo:
    def thing(self,args):
        print "No, really. Don't ever do this."

class bar:
    def thing(self,args):
        print "This is completely unrelated."
```

This is bad. Don't do this. But if you **did**, you could call `thing(args)` and *something* would happen. This can potentially be a good thing if you plan accordingly:

```
class Person:
    def bio(self):
        print "I'm a person!"

class Student(Person):
    def bio(self):
        Person.bio(self)
        print "I'm studying %s" % self.major
```

The above code makes it so that if you create an object of `Student` class and call `bio`, it'll do all the stuff that would have happened if it was of `Person` class that had its own `bio` called **and** it'll do its own thing afterwards.

This gets into inheritance and some other stuff you might not have seen yet, but look forward to it.

Comment: I fail to understand how this is bad. `thing()`, `foo().thing()` and `bar().thing()` are obviously different functions; there’s no way you can take one for another.

Answer (score 2):

To me, self like a scope definer, with self.foo() and self.bar indicating the function and the parameter defined in the class and not those defines in the other places.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another function with the same name outside your class.
`self` is an object reference to the object itself, therefore, they are same. 
Python methods are not called in the context of the object itself. `self` in Python may be used to deal with custom object models or something.