# python function behaves differently

Tags: python, function

Declaring a class with method 'print' with param 'self':

```
class First:
  def print(self): 
    print('working') 
    return 2
```

Trying to call the method without instantiating the class:
`First.print()` getting below message:

```
TypeError: print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Now when instantiating the class and accessing the method: it's working.

```
first = First()
first.print()

# working
# 2
```

Now defining the same class without any param in method `print`:

```
class First:
  def print():
    print('working')
    return 2
```

Calling the same method without instantiating the class and it's working:

```
First.print()

# working
# 2
```

Without defining the method param, python method behaving like Static. Is it true or something else?

Comment: Please correct formatting of your question (especially the source code)

Comment: In the first execution you try to call it without instantiating it, therefor there is no 'self' to pass to the method, which is why it fails.

Comment: In that examples is obviously that an static method not use self, such as your second example. You can see more examples in related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679803/python-calling-method-without-self

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification..

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the bound variable or object. so it needs instantiation. where as without `self` method becomes static (class method in python context) and can be called using Class Name. 
Also you should write `@classmethod` decorator above the method definition. so that it is clearly state that it is a `classmethod`.

```
class First:
  @classmethod
  def print(cls):
    print('working')
    return 2
First.print()
```

For your reference 
https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the difference between his second example, and using `@staticmethod`?

Comment: It would be pythonic way if you write @staticmethod. His 2nd exampe is basically a static method.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, it is a function of *one* parameter. So, `Class.f()` fails. In the second example, it is a function of *zero* parameters. So, `Class.f()` works.

When you create an instance, the first parameter is automatically bound to that instance, and you need to pass `n-1` parameters. So, it works in your first example, but it won't work in your second.