# Why does this recursive function call require 'self'

Tags: python

This is my solution for a reverse linked list problem. I dont understand why when I call `reverseList(head.next)` within the function, there is an error unless I include `self`

```
 #Recursive Solution
 def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        
        p = self.reverseList(head.next)
        head.next.next = head
        head.next = None
        return p
```

Error without self -

```
NameError: name 'reverseList' is not defined
    p = reverseList(head.next)
Line 22 in reverseList (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().reverseList(param_1)
Line 45 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 56 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: recursive function or method?

Comment: You always have to call a method via an object (e.g. `self.`). That's normal for Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18679803/3890632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a method of a class, and the first argument refers to the instance of that class.

It's not clear at all why it is a method, since it reverses a different list than itself and doesn't use any of its own attributes except for that method.

This should work just as well:

```
def reverseList(head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    if not head or not head.next:
        return head
    
    p = reverseList(head.next)
    head.next.next = head
    head.next = None
    return p
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode` is actually a method (it belongs to a class). The `self` indicates that the method access the object, which contains the state of the object. This is not the case here, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @staticmethod decorator, which tells the interpreter, that this method doesn't need the acces to the object. Also you can use it without constructing the object. Actually static methods are just normal functions defined inside the class mostly for better code organisation - and for your purpose, normal function instead of method is enough.

```
@staticmethod
def reverseList(head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
```

When you use self inside function, you just have to replace it with your class object.

```
        p = Solution.reverseList(head.next)
```

EDIT:
In fact here, hence you're using the class instance, not specific object, even better will be class method.

```
@classmethod
def reverseList(cls, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
...
p = cls.reverseList(head.next)
```